# What is/are the process(es) leading to the mispronunciation of the word "extra"?

Tags: phonetics

I find that it is not uncommon for the word *extra* to be pronounced without the letter 'x' being enunciated such that it sounds like /ˈɛkʃᵗrə/ instead of /ˈɛkstrə/. That is the /s/ sound is substituted with a /ʃ/ sound and the /t/ sound becomes much more diluted.

Are these two changes brought about by a single process or two distinct processes? What is/are it/they called?

Comment: Related: [Why is "str" sometimes pronounced as "shtr"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84836/why-is-str-sometimes-pronounced-as-shtr), [About s being replaced by the voiceless postalveolar fricative in the US](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/30111/about-s-being-replaced-by-the-voiceless-postalveolar-fricative-in-the-us)

Comment: There's lots of tongue movement required to pronounce all the parts of `xtr`. Some of them get lost in the process.