# Palatalization of the initial "s" in words starting with "str-"

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, accent, consonants, palatalization

Sometimes I hear native speakers pronounce the *s* at the beginning of a word as [ʃ]. For example, *straight* as [ʃtreɪt], or *struggle* as [ʃtrʌɡl]. It sounds like German words.

Is it a certain English dialect, a specific accent, or just an idiolect?

Comment: In my experience, many Hiberno-English speakers use that to soften the intensity of a statement and introduce some humour into it. Examples: *big shtyle*; *the hill is fair shteep!*". I haven't heard it outside Ireland.

Comment: @Jubobs what made me ask this question is to hear it from Britons and Americans from time to time. Not regularly, but not rarely too. Of course, I was not on the position to exactly identify the origin of the speaker, but they were native. Maybe that `many` that you referred to is spreading a kind of fashion?!?

Comment: Also, the s in student is pronounced like sh by most English people (shchoodent, /ʃtʃʉːdənʔ/).

Comment: I've lived all my life in England and I can't recall anyone English saying "Shchoodent" (unless drunk). "S-choodent" , sometimes (with t turning into a ch but the S pronounced separately), "ss-tyoo-dent" sometimes - eg: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gV-kY9JuqDE . "Choozday" is probably more frequent than "T-yoozday" - in both cases, it's the plosive that has been affected, not the sibilant.

Comment: Does pronouncing `s` as [ʃ] in the middle of words fall within the scope of your question? I've just remembered [this instance](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3roG09O6T4#t=04m35s) by an American; note that he pronounces *administration* as *adminishtration*...

Comment: I think Peter Shor is right, and that you are just hearing the *t* in *-tr-* combos being pronounced /tʃ/.  For example, *tree* is often pronounced as if it were spelled *chree*. This is as normal, and common, as the palatalization that occurs when people say *did you* quickly enough for it to come out as *didja*: it is just something your mouth does.

Comment: @tchrist, I believe that if you pronounce *tree* as *chree*, there is also a tendency to pronounce *street* as *shchreet*. And in fact, on [forvo.com](http://www.forvo.com/word/wall_street_journal/#en), you can hear "Wall Street Journal" pronounced this way (third speaker). Once you  change 't' to 'ch', there's a natural tendency to change 's' to 'sh'. I'd be surprised if anybody said *shtreet* without palatalizing the 't', but I think *shchreet* is reasonably common.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is "str" sometimes pronounced as "shtr"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84836/why-is-str-sometimes-pronounced-as-shtr)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pronunciation of voiceless alveolar fricative /s/ as ʃ (/sh/) in slang?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10309/pronunciation-of-voiceless-alveolar-fricative-s-as-%ca%83-sh-in-slang)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Palatal vowels (*i*), semivowels (*y*), and liquids (*r*) often influence the sound of preceding consonants, a process called [palatalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization). This is most obvious with dental consonants like *t* and *s,* which typically become *tch* and *sh.* For example, *train* often sounds like *tchrain*.

Palatalization is consistent for some English forms, like the *shun* sound of the *-tion* suffix. It is weaker or inconsistent for others, like the *tr-* and *str-* consonant clusters. Native speakers generally don't notice the variation unless you exaggerate it – *train* and *tchrain* are allophones. However, the subtle palatalization of *straight* could easily sound like *shchrait* to a non-native speaker.

Answer (score 6):

You're absolutely right, there is a subtle *sh* sound. I've just tried it myself and I can detect different positions of my mouth and tongue as I say *str* words, compared to words beginning simply with *s* (excluding sugar and sure of course) and other *s* and consonant clusters. I have no knowledge as to whether this is more marked in different regions, but I guess that as a non-native speaker you have tuned into this subtle variation whereas a native speaker would hardly notice any difference. The *r* sound is more of a vowel sound than a consonant in English and my mouth seems to anticipate this as it says the *str.*

Comment: +1: [Here](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-do-we-pronounce-train.html) is a blog posting discussing the way words beginning with "tr" turn into "chr", so "train" becomes "chrain". I think a large number of English speakers do this to some degree. It isn't surprising that "straight" might become "shchraight" (which would sound like "shtraight").

Comment: +1 for pointing this out – I do this subtly and didn't even realize it. @PeterShor: Funny coincidence that I chose _chrain_ as an example for my explanation of palatalization.

Comment: It's also worth noting that American /r/ in /tr/ is rounded as well as palatalized, like many speakers' /ʃ/. That increases the resemblance.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether the OP has heard Hiberno-English speakers introducing some light-hearted humour by mimicking a well-known verbal mannerism of the actor Sean Connery? Not uncommon in Scotland. Mr. Connery comes from Edinburgh, as do I, and I don't recognise this as typical of an Edinburgh accent.

Answer (score -1):

I notice that most NYC Subway conductors do this, as in "14th Shtreet, 42nd Shtreet next."  Outside the subway, I notice this pronunciation among many African-American men in NYC. I presume, perhaps erroneously, that this is an inner-city, macho-culture thing originating from a desire not to sound effeminate.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, and answers at StackExchange are expected to be definitive, and include research and references; please do not post personal anecdotes or unsupported speculation. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).