# Different sounds of "t"

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, morphology

Why do we sometimes pronounce t as /t/, whereas other times we pronounce it as /ʧ/ or /ʃ/?

- /t/ in town,
- /ʧ/ in natural
- /ʃ/ in hamartia/tertiary

Is there any special rule for these?

Comment: Note that pronunciation will usually evolve before [a standardized spelling](http://www.ruf.rice.edu/~kemmer/Histengl/spelling.html), so that the question might at least as well be posed why letter "t" was used in the accepted spelling of words with such pronunciations.

Comment: These words all used to be pronounced with 't' sounds, and the spelling stayed the same when the sound changed. Certainly, "natural" didn't change to 'ʧ' until after the [Great Vowel Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift) turned 'u' into its modern pronunciation. The Wikipedia article I linked to says this was around 1700, a century after spelling was standardized.

Comment: Related: [Pronunciation of voiceless alveolar fricative /s/ as ʃ (/sh/) in slang](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/10309/), [Why is “str” sometimes pronounced as “shtr”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/84836/), and the questions linked from there. Or just check our [palatalization](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palatalization) tag. On a general note, as others have pointed out, it is not letters that are pronounced, but sounds that are spelled. And for spelling you have to consider not just sound, but also other things like etymology, disambiguation of homophones, etc.

Comment: Actually, these things can be quite complicated. For example, the OED says that *"partial"* was spelt with a *"c"* or an *"s"* in Middle English; the word came from Old French *"parcial"*. So it presumably changed pronunciation from /t/ in Latin to /s/ in Old French. Middle English borrowed it from Old French with an /s/ sound, which changed to /ʃ/ in Modern English. When English spelling was fixed, the spelling was somehow changed to a *"t"* to match the Latin etymology (*partialis*).

Comment: I certainly don’t pronounce the t in _hamartia_ as /ʃ/ (to the extent that I pronounce the word at all, that is). It’s a regular ol’ /t/ sound to me.

Answer (score 0):

Its not about 't' precisely. Same is the case with c in cake, c in recess, c in chef or any other example of that kind.

1) It depends on the origin of the word. say, French or Latin (for example)
2) It depends on the letter that follows it ( This at times gives a combined effect on the word)
3) Also, spellings of some words change over time. This may be noted too !